# Tampermonkey .click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I'm trying to auto click a button in tampermonkey, but for some reason the code isn't executing. Though, if I put the code in console and run it, it works fine.

Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    path = window.location.pathname;
    setTimeout(autoTraderReady, 10);
    $('#VehicleApplyButton').click();
});
<table id="VehicleApplyButton" class="x-btn va-apply-button x-btn-noicon x-column" cellspacing="0"><tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left"><tr><td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-tc"></td><td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-mc"><em class=" x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><button class=" x-btn-text" id="ext-gen147" type="button">&nbsp;</button></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-bc"></td><td class="x-btn-br"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Button does not switch dynamically, tried doing an alert when the function runs, doesn't alert me.

Comment: @wOxxOm i added in a setTimeout for 5000ms but it still didn't work

Comment: @wOxxOm added a little bit more info, not sure what else to add

Comment: I think the problem is that `#VehicleApplyButton` is a table, not a button. There's a button inside the table. Try clicking it: `$('#VehicleApplyButton button').click();`

Comment: @wOxxOm no errors being reported on console, using other jquery stuff inside the script that are acting fine

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes Give a way to test your problem. How do you expect anyone to give you an answer when there's no way to give you more than a guess?

Comment: @TomášZato I gave what i tried, code I used, and problem statement, give me ideas on what to do in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code:

```
1. $(document).ready(function() {
2.     path = window.location.pathname;
3.     setTimeout(autoTraderReady, 10);
4.     $('#VehicleApplyButton').click();
5. });
```

and based upon your comment below, the click on line 4 is expected to trigger an AJAX request fired from a `.click` listener elsewhere in your document.  If this listener exists within an external script, my suspicion is that the other listener is an not around in time to catch the click event you're triggering.  That is to say, it starts listening *after* your click has already fired.

`$(document).ready` only waits for only the DOM to load, not external scripts; try changing line 1 to `$(window).on('load', function(){...});` instead.

If that fails, try adding following debugging lines:

```
1. $(document).ready(function() {
2.     console.log( $('#VehicleApplyButton') );
3.     $('#VehicleApplyButton').click(function(e){ console.log( e ) } );
4.     $('#VehicleApplyButton').click();
5. });
```

**Line 2** - confirm #VehicleApplyButton exists

**Line 3** - confirm click event is propagating

*Note: my first draft overlooked that `jQuery` interprets `.click()` as a shortcut for `.trigger('click')` with no params, rather than the listener `.on('click',[data],handler)` with 1-2 params.  Thanks for the polite correction, @robertklep.*

Comment: `$(...).click()` [is a shortcut for](https://api.jquery.com/click/) `$(...).trigger('click')`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how `click` is invoked w/out params, @robertklep. Will modify my answer shortly.

Comment: When the user clicks on the #VehicleApplyButton, the client sends some data to the server and the server responds with some JSON. I can't really figure out any of the parameters for the client request. The other lines that you are talking about, really wouldn't affect the outcome of the .click() at all.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes have you tried my edited suggestions above?  What was the result?

Comment: @Cam, sorry for not accepting the answer, looks and works great, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For me it had to do with the particular page that I was triggering the event on.

Neither jQuery.click() nor plain elem.click() were working.
I solved as a workaround creating a MouseEvent like so:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.submitButton');

let clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        clientX: 150,
        clientY: 150
});

btn.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

So maybe it's got to do with EventBubbling for you too.

Comment: How to get mouse coordinates according to selected element ?

Comment: Didn't work for me, even the element are selected correctly

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me!